# C++ function argument and struct errors

Tags: c++, function, struct, parameters, arguments

I am currently coding a program that will allow a user to input a direction and move a robot along a coordinate plane. I am new to C++, so a few of the errors I am getting are confusing me. Could someone please explain my errors?

When I call function init_room, it says there are too few arguments. The same thing happens when I call init_robot. They both have pointer parameters. How would I go about fixing this issue?

When I call function move in the main function, it says the expression must be a modifiable value. What does this mean?

Thanks for the help!

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

typedef struct room {
    int x;
    int y;
};

typedef struct robot {
    room *current_room;
    int current_x;
    int current_y;
    int model;
};

void init_robot(robot *r) {
    r->current_room->x;
    r->current_room->y;
    r->current_x = 0;
    r->current_y = 0;
    //Assign model number
    r->model;
}

void init_room(room *r) {
    cin >> r->x;
    cin >> r->y;

}

char move(robot *r, int direction) {
        if (direction == 'N' || direction == 'n')
        {
            r->current_y + 1;
        }
        else if (direction == 'S' || direction == 's')
        {
            r->current_y - 1;
        }
        else if (direction == 'E' || direction == 'e')
        {
            r->current_x + 1;
        }
        else if (direction == 'W' || direction == 'w')
        {
            r->current_x - 1;
        }
        else
        {
            direction = 'x';
            return direction;
        }

    int main() {
        char direction;
        char restart;

        cout << "What size would you like the room to be?";

        room rr;

        init_room();

        robot r; initrobot();

        while (true) {

                cout << "Your robot is in a room with the dimensions (" << rr.x << "," << rr.yy << "). at location (" << r.current_x << "," << r.current_y << ")." << endl;
                cout << "What direction would you like to move? N (North), E (east), S(South), or W(West)?";
                do {
                cin >> direction;

                move(direction) = direction;
                if (direction = 'x') {
                    cout << "Invalid direction. Please enter N, E, S, or W.";
                    }
                while (direction == 'x');

                cout << "Current position is" << endl;

    //          if (r.current_x <= rr.x && r.current_y <= rr.y)
        //      {
            //      cout << "Error, your robot is out of the room bounds. Your robot has exited the room. Would you like to enter another room? Y or N?";
                    cin >> restart;
            //} while (restart == 'Y' || restart == 'y');
                    }

            system("pause");
            return 0;
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The functions init_room and init_robot both take a single parameter each. So, your calls to them should be like

```
init_room(&rr);
init_robot(&r);
```

`move` returns an rvalue of type `char`, and rvalues cannot be modified. It can only be used as an input to some other expression. I expect you do not know what an rvalue is and it would be a good idea for you to research this as it is an important concept in C++. (Quick version: an rvalue is what might be on the right side of an `=` and is basically read-only.)

Comment: Thank you both for the help! @GaryMakin I will definitely do some research into what an rvalue is. Thanks for the tip.